Azure DevOps 2022 R2 Server - GIT branch read permissions
Is it possble to deny read permissions to a repository, and grant read to a branch for a user(s) and/or group(s) of a group of branches within a given path.
reviewed repository security and the read permission looks only to be at the repository level and not branch level.
documentation seems to suggest that this is possbile; however this is not currently working the our azure devops 2022 R2 server; we need this feature as we have multiple teams of 3rd party developers committing code to a repository that needs to be isolated/none visible to each other.

permissions per-branch? Nah... branches are just pointers to commits... you might try to hack your way into this by using the files created for each ref.... but this is not something that will fly for long, I am sure. Keep in mind that git's model is not about centralized stuff, it's distributed and each person owns their repos so no point in trying to force this concept.

TL;DR read permissions can be set at the repository level only.
More details
Read permission can be set at the repository level for Azure Git repositories:

Readers can clone, fetch, and explore the contents of a repository; also, can create, comment on, vote, and Contribute to pull requests.
This permission doesn't seem to be available at the branch level though:


we have multiple teams of 3rd party developers committing code to a repository that needs to be isolated/none visible to each other.

You might have to reconsider your repositories/branches strategy, e.g. create dedicated repositories with different permissions for each team.
